# How to fix " TransientPropertyValueException" error in Spring Boot

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to save (POST) with a json structure, and I need to use a foreign key (idClient and idUser), but it produces the described error, I do not know if I am sending it correctly, the idClient created it manually, not auto generated.

And tried to solve it with annotations but I could not.

```
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClient", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Pres> presCollection1;


@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idUser", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Pres> presCollection2;



 @ManyToOne

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("id_client")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client",  referencedColumnName = "identi")
    private Person idClient;


    @ManyToOne

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("id_user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user",  referencedColumnName = "identi")
    private Person idUser;



JSON TO SEND


{ 
    "date": "2019-03-24T05:00:00.000Z",
    "lastDate": "2019-09-24T05:00:00.000Z",
    "idClient":{"idClient":11},
    "idUser":{"idUser":12}

}
```

I need to save the client and user ids

Comment: show full stack and also the transactional method wehre you do the save

Comment: @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object>registrar(@Valid @RequestBody Prest prest){ 
        Prest prest  = service.save(prest); 
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(emp.getIdPrest()).toUri(); 
        return ResponseEntity.created(((URI) location).normalize()).build();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REMOVE}
```

you have to merge those values so give cascade type only merge.